# Using Riemann Sums to Evaluate a Peculiar Function

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

SE,

I've been mulling over the following problem, which involves using Riemann sums to evaluate

$\int_{0}^1 (x^4+\cos(x)) dx$

And I am a little stuck. Here is my attempt at a solution:
[I've put the step numbers in for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBaFf.jpg)

I would really appreciate some guidance - I feel like I am at the cusp of a solution.

Comment: What exactly do you want? I'm not going to follow links in order to read a question. It should be self-contained to the highest degree possible.

Comment: @Nij Understood - I've thus foregone the use of an image to describe the question (my solution, however, still is in this form). I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct through most of the steps.

The following should help you finish.

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\cos\left(\frac{i}{n}\right) &= \frac{\sin\left(\frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n}\right)} \\ &= \frac{2\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{2n\sin\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)} \end{align}$$

Since,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2n\sin\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{\frac{1}{2n}} = 1,$$

you can conclude

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\cos\left(\frac{i}{n}\right) = 2 \sin(1/2)\cos(1/2) = \sin(1).$$

Comment: Thank you. I see how your independent consideration of $\cos$ and then its 'linking' to the '$\sin$' of the numerator in the simplified expression helped you arrive at a conclusion